# How to save date (dd.mm.yyyy) in java

Tags: java, date

I am getting a date in the form of dd.mm.yyyy and want to save it as a proper object. It should be comparable to another date object. How do I realize this?

Comment: [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: But this does not contain a simple compareTo method. Is it possible to convert this into unix time?

Comment: But `Date` does have `compareTo`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleDateFormat as this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("12/05/2015");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
String input = "03.01.2015";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(input, formatter);
DateTime now = new DateTime();

System.out.println(dt.compareTo(now));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String string = "03.01.2015";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Date d = sdf.parse("19.05.2090");  
        System.out.println(d);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The question asks for `dd.MM` rather than `MM.dd`